# Run automated tests from test plans gives error No test sources found

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests

I have some NUnit tests and have worked through [the instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops) to run Azure Test Plans. The test binaries build from a build script that links a test dll to the pipeline setup per the instructions. All appears to work with the following pipeline

[image]

Until [step 4 of Run the automated tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops#run-the-automated-tests) which fails with errors:

`No test sources found`

and

`[error]The slice of type 'Execution' is 'Aborted' because of the error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException: No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter criteria is correct.`

The test logs say

`Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters`
`SourceFilter: *.dll TestCaseFilter:`

My test assembly is actually called `MyProject.Test.dll` and it was built with these instructions

`/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\Test\\"`

In the previous step to running any test the artifacts are downloaded like this:

[image]

If I change the `Test run` type to `Test assemblies` in the Azure test script

[image]

I get an error from the Azure Test Plan run saying

[image]

However, it's possible to "release" the new test script, which appears to succeed like this

[image]

Though in reality there was a similar error, fixed later below:

`[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: **\bin\x64\Release\*Test*.dll.`

The NUnit test run fine from Visual Studio, they build ok, but I can't trigger them to run from the Azure Devops, aaargh. There were 2 problems there:

1. There was no build task to copy `dll` and `config` libraries to the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\Test\\` directory. I added a "copy files" task to the build script.

[image]

2. Once that was done I could see in the "Download Artifacts" stage that test libraries were downloaded to the test directory

[image]

I set the release pipeline search folder to include the path to the downloaded artifacts

[image]

Now the Test Assemblies run via a "release"

[image]

How can I run this using the Test Run selection?

[image]

There is still error:

`[error]The slice of type 'Execution' is 'Aborted' because of the error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.TestsNotFoundException: No test assemblies found on the test machine matching the source filter criteria or no tests discovered matching test filter criteria. Verify that test assemblies are present on the machine and test filter criteria is correct`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your detailed description, the test .dll file  should already exist in the corresponding folder (`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.../.../Release`).

Since you could run the `Test Assemblies` successfully in Release Pipeline, the Search Path and filter in the VsTest Task could be right.

You need to check the .dll file connected to the test case in `Test Case -> Associated Automation`.

[image]

You need to make sure that the .dll from `Automated test storage` exists in your Release artifacts.

In other words, you need to make sure that the .dll in **Test Case -> Automated test storage** is `MyProject.Test.dll`

If not, you need to reconnect the correct .dll file.

Here is a doc about [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but I have already done this and yes the test points to the correct test library dll. So the Test Assemblies runs, but the Test Run does not ?!!

Comment: Hi @rupweb. Test run could be related to test case. Based on my test, when the test case points to the different test library dll, the test run will fail with the same error, but the Test Assemblies could run successfully. Can you try to re-associate test case in visual studio?

Comment: I found in the log that the `xxx.test.dll` file has been downloaded to the specified folder, so I think the path should be correct

Comment: Is it because it's an NUnit test and the Test Run can only see VsTest?

Comment: Hi @rupweb. As far as i know, test run can support nunit test.